# Is it possible to limit the number of versions stashed by Amazon S3's versioning?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, versioning

I'm currently working on migrating the file backup system for my office to Amazon S3. The basic backup is working like a charm but I'm looking to make it a little more robust. Specifically I am looking to add version control for the files in the bucket (using Amazon "Versioning") but there is no mention (that I can find) of a way to limit the number of old versions stashed per file (ie: "File x" has a maximum of 5 previous versions at any given time).

Is it possible to place limits on the number of versions stored per file? Or am I stuck with an unlimited propagation of file versions over time if I go this route?

I've been digging through the AWS forums (as well as anywhere else I look) and have yet to find anything. Any info would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently you would need to list and erase old versions manually, as there is no user defined version limit.

Comment: After 9 years I still cannot believe that a 'specific number of revisions' is not possible or offered by AWS.  Why not?!

Answer (score 44):

While I don't believe Amazon added the option to limit the versions to a specific count of revisions (say "5" previous revisions), you can certainly use S3 lifecycle management, which does support rules based on time.  You can use `NoncurrentVersionTransition` to transition the old version to a different storage class, and you can use `NoncurrentVersionExpiration` to finally delete an old revision.

So if you backup your data at a predefined time interval (say once a week), then if you set your `NoncurrentVersionExpiration` to 6 weeks, you'll only keep the last 5 (maybe 6?) versions.

Reference: [AWS S3 Lifecycle](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/intro-lifecycle-rules.html)

Comment: Example lifecycle rule: Removing Expired Object Delete Markers https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/lifecycle-configuration-examples.html#lifecycle-config-conceptual-ex7

Comment: If you're looking for a walkthrough of how to do it via the online console: https://darktraining.com/2017/12/23/S3-version-cleanup/

Comment: That's not a solution, if you backup every week and and object doesn't change for several week you will loose old versions of it.

Answer (score 14):

YES is's possible @paul-littlefield @user3606089

creating a lifecycle rule, you can specify when non current version of the objects will expire and "Number of newer versions to retain - Optional"

If you want to keep a certain number of versions, despite how old they are, set the expiration to 1 day and the number of versions you want to keep in the second field.

[image: settings]

[image: behaviour]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is practically possible.

We can create a lifecycle policy, which will delete non-concurrent versions (previous versions) 1 day after it has become non-concurrent version.
1 day is the hard limit, you cannot change it to 0 days.

Run the below commands to keep the latest 3 non-concurrent versions.

```bash
cat << EOF > lifecycle_policy.json
{
   "Rules": [
       {
           "ID": "Keep only the latest 4 versions of a File",
           "Filter": {},
           "Status": "Enabled",
           "NoncurrentVersionExpiration": {
               "NoncurrentDays": 1,
               "NewerNoncurrentVersions": 3
           }
       }
   ]
}
EOF
```

```bash
BUCKET_NAME=<bucket-name>

aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration \
    --bucket $BUCKET_NAME \
    --lifecycle-configuration file://lifecycle_policy.json
```

This policy will keep 3 non-concurrent versions + 1 active version = 4 versions in Total.

The bucket policy will take some time to take effect if you have a large bucket.
Changes in the s3 Storage Lens might take time to reflect